# search results and pagination wrong if embedded view or block in result set

Tags: drupal-7, pagination, drupal-search

I have two content types (in a Drupal 7.20 environment) which embed views or blocks.  When I allow those content types in search results, the results page goes sideways whenever those content types are represented in the result set: the pager shows a different number of total pages from one results page to the next, or disappears entirely after I hit Next (!), fewer than 10 results show per page (yet there's a pager...), etc., etc.

If I disallow those content types (via Custom Search), I don't see any problems with pagination, etc.

What I have noticed is that the actual views/blocks get executed when the search results page is constructed - it's not merely a matter of hits being found in the search_index table.

Anybody know how to address this problem?

(I've searched through stackoverflow, and issues for Search and Custom Search on Drupal.org - no joy.)

Thanks in advance, 
Lee

[Edit: fixed a couple of typos...]
[3/17/13 Edit: The problem turns out to be due to the pager for the view or block that is included in the search result set.  If the view is in the result set, but doesn't have a pager, there is no problem.  My solution, therefore, is to detect that I'm on a search results page in hook_views_query_alter() (by looking at the request URI) and set

```
$view->items_per_page = 0;
```

which effectively gets rid of the view's pager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I didn't realize I could answer my question - not sure how that's different from editing the question to include the answer, but I'll put my answer here as well, anyway.]

The problem turns out to be due to the pager for the view or block that is included in the search result set. If the view is in the result set, but doesn't have a pager, there is no problem. My solution, therefore, is to detect that I'm on a search results page in hook_views_query_alter() (by looking at the request URI) and set

```
$view->items_per_page = 0;
```

which effectively gets rid of the view's pager.

Comment: you should mark the answer as "accepted" (tick on the left) to stop the question comming up in "unanswered" :)